# exit() vs _exit() : Does calling _exit() ensures closing of all open fd and sockets?

Tags: c, linux, exit

I have used `exit()` to terminate the process. I do not have any exit handlers registered also I do not care about flushing buffers on exit, so thought of using `_exit()` as more robust method to terminate process.

The only question is, does `_exit()` handles closing of all open file descriptors and open sockets gracefully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `exit` calls `_exit`. From TLPI:

> The following actions are performed by exit():
>
> - Exit handlers are called
> - The stdio stream buffers are flushed
> - **The _exit() system call is invoked**

The [standard page for _exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html) says this:

> **All of the file descriptors**, directory streams, conversion
>   descriptors, and message catalog descriptors open in the calling
>   process shall be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. Actually, on most platforms, operating system closes files and sockets for terminated process, so it doesn't matter if it finished with `_exit()`, `exit()`, `assert(false)` or `kill -KILL`.

Note that stdio `FILE *` streams are NOT closed correctly by `_exit()` and any unwritten (still buffered) data will be lost.